# Cannot create PostgreSQL with CloudFormation but works with web interface

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I'm trying to create a Serverless V2 Aurora PostgreSQL cluster and an instance with CloudFormation.

It works fine when using the AWS web interface but when using CloudFormation (trough Serverless) I get

> Error: CREATE_FAILED: auroraCluster (AWS::RDS::DBCluster) Resource
> handler returned message: "**The engine mode serverless you requested is
> currently unavailable**.

CF Template:

```
# Database
auroraCluster:
  Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
  Properties: 
    AutoMinorVersionUpgrade: 'true'
    AvailabilityZones:
      - eu-north-1a
      - eu-north-1b
      - eu-north-1c
    DatabaseName:
      publisher
    DeletionProtection: !If [isProd, 'true', 'false']
    Engine: aurora-postgresql
    EngineMode: serverless
    EngineVersion: '14.6'

auroraInstance:
  Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
  Properties: 
    AllowMajorVersionUpgrade: !If [isProd, 'true', 'false']
    AutoMinorVersionUpgrade: 'true'
    AvailabilityZone: !Sub ${AWS::Region}a
    DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref auroraCluster
    DBInstanceIdentifier: ${self:service}-rds-${sls:stage}
    DeleteAutomatedBackups: !If [isProd, 'false', 'true']
    DeletionProtection: !If [isProd, 'true', 'false']
    Engine: aurora-postgresql
    ManageMasterUserPassword: 'true'
    MasterUsername: postgres
    MasterUserSecret:
      SecretArn: !Ref secretRds
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serverless aurora for postgress 14.6 is only supported for [serverless v2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless-v2.html). This requires different setup then you have. For example, you have to provide `ServerlessV2ScalingConfiguration`, delete `EngineMode` and use `DBInstanceClass` set to `db.serverless`. For example:

```
Resources:

    auroraCluster:
        Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
        Properties:
            #AutoMinorVersionUpgrade: 'true'
            DatabaseName:
                publisher
            Engine: aurora-postgresql
            EngineVersion: '14.6'
            MasterUsername: "trdyd"
            MasterUserPassword: "gfsdg344231"
            ServerlessV2ScalingConfiguration:
                MinCapacity: 1
                MaxCapacity: 4


    auroraInstance:
        Type: 'AWS::RDS::DBInstance'
        Properties:
            Engine: aurora-postgresql
            DBInstanceClass: db.serverless
            DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref auroraCluster
```

Obviously you have to adjust the above example, which **works**, to what exactly you need, taking into account serverless v2 capabilities.

Comment: That was it, thank you! The documentation is certainly lacking in this scenario. Nowhere in the docs for DBInstanceClass (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html) is db.serverless mentioned.

Comment: The page you cite is from the RDS User Guide. The corresponding page in the Aurora User Guide does talk about Serverless v2: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html